# Do DocuSign integrator keys have an expiry date?

Tags: token, docusignapi

Once you have a valid integrator key in production, does it ever need to be renewed? I don't see any expiry date, so I assume not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, integrator keys do not expire.

Comment: To add a little bit more info here, the keys cannot be deleted however they CAN be disabled, especially if they violate platform API rules and limits.